# Formik , fields fill validation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, formik

I'm working with Formik and I got problem with field fill validation. Inside `<Formik>` depending on state i'm rendering forms with input. If fields are not filled out make button "next" disable.How make validation only on that fields that are rendered ?

```
displayForms = (values, step) => {

    const formsComponents = {
      1:<Step1 {...values} />
      2:<Step2 education={values.education}/>,
    };

    switch (step) {
      case 1:
        return formsComponents[1];
      case 2:
        return formsComponents[2];
      default:
        return formsComponents[1];
    }
  };

          <Formik
            ref={this.resume}
            initialValues={this.initialValues}
            validate={values => {
              if (values) {
                return !value ? "Required" : "";
              }
            }}
            render={({ values, isValid }) => {
              return (
                <Form>
                  <div className="jobs-resume-panes">
                      {this.displayForms(
                        values,
                        isValid,
                        this.state.activeStep
                      )}
                  </div>                  
                  <div className="jobs-resume-controls">
                      {activeStep === allSteps ? (
                        <button
                          onClick={() => this.submitResume(values, isValid)}
                        >
                          Save
                        </button>
                      ) : (
                        <button
                          disabled={this.state.isDisabled}
                          onClick={this.goNextStep}
                        >
                          Next
                        </button>
                      )}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </Form>
```

Comment: You should consider using `yup` validation library. It works great with Formik and will let you achieve the desired result without writing complex code.

Comment: @LiJonas I almost solved my problem with yup, but right now when I rendering another component I need to set isValid prop to false. Do you have any idea how to do it?

Comment: You can do it manually by assigning a new variable to FormProps.isValid and changing it accordingly.

Comment: @LiJonas Could you please write an example, I didn't get how to make it

Comment: Sorry, wrote it wrong. You cannot set isValid directly, you need to either to use errors/setErrors or status/setStatus like in the example I made in this sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-formik-full-example-ux5tk

Comment: Can you share a codesandbox with your current progress @YerlanYeszhanov

Comment: @DaniVijay I already fix it . Thank you